# Does anything follow from falsity in Aristotelian Logic?

Tags: logic, aristotle

In the usual propositional logic, proving a contradiction means that one can prove any other proposition; this on the face of it , and when one turns it over is quite strange - and there are modern paraconsistent logics that attempt to circumvent this.

Does Aristotelian logic, as Aristotle used it, suffer from the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few "propositional" laws used in [Aristotle's logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/).

One of the methods of proof used by A. in deriving figures form the basic ones is [reductio (*anagein*) through the impossible (*dia to adunaton*)](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#MetProPerDedConRed), i.e. the principle of *indirect proof*.

An early use of [Consequentia mirabilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentia_mirabilis) has been found; see William Kneale, [Aristotle and the Consequentia Mirabilis](http://www.jstor.org/stable/628635?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (1957), in the lost [Protrepticus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protrepticus_(Aristotle)).

But it seems that an explicit use of [Ex falso (sequitur) quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) is not present into his logical works.

Of course, the [rejection of contradictions](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-noncontradiction/) is the "firmest" principle of A.' logic and metaphysics.

An aristotelian *locus* that seemingly involves "explosion", but in the context of metaphysics and not logic, is *Metaph*, IV.4, 1007b19–on :

> Again, if all contradictories are true of the same subject at the same time,
>   evidently all things will be one. For the same thing will be a trireme, a wall, and a man, if it is equally possible to affirm and to deny anything of anything [...].

---

See [Aristotle on Non-contradiction : Dialetheism and Paraconsistency](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-noncontradiction/#11) for a proposed "paraconsistent" interpretation of some passages found in A.'s works.

---

According to [Ernest Addison Moody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Addison_Moody), [Truth and Consequence in Medieval Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=i0ruAAAAMAAJ) (1953), page 90, in [Buridan](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buridan/), [Consequentiae](https://books.google.it/books?id=6CbpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA201), (Book I, ch.8, rule 7) we have:

> "Ad omnem copulativam ex duabus contradictoriis constitutam sequi quamlibet aliam, etiam consequentia formali"

that we can translate as :

> > **p ∧ ¬ p ⊢ q**

See [Medieval Theories of Consequence](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequence-medieval/) for an overview:

> Buridan's treatise on consequence and the treatises inspired by it, most notably Albert of Saxony's (a chapter of his *Perutilis logica*) and Marsilius of Inghen's treatise on consequence. There is also the interesting commentary on the *Prior Analyics* formerly attributed to [Scotus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/duns-scotus/#ScoWor) which is thought to have been composed before or in any case independently of Buridan's treatise. [...] This tradition can be referred to as the Parisian/continental tradition on consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the response; it does beg the question how did the PNC come about in logic, the wiki article referenced doesn't say; also, The article on dialectism in A mentions that the sygollistic is reported as being paraconsistent in the *prior analytics* - though it doesn't say why, or in what sense.

Comment: There are passages I've noted too in A's *metaphysics* which curiously sounds he's using some kind non-traditional onto-logic.